# "A dream where I was walking" vs. "a dream when I was walking"

Tags: word-choice, when, where

I often find it hard to choose between "where" and "when". For instance:

> - One time, I had a dream when I was walking...
> - One time, I had a dream where I was walking...

Should I use *when*, since I initially mentioned a period in time ("one time")? If so, under what circumstances should I use *where*?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. Please edit to clarify what exactly you are confused about and to show what references you have already consulted and what you found. Thanks.

Comment: @MετάEd Wonder how any research could help here. cf. mattacular below.

Comment: @Kris Anyone who wants to ask how to use English without first doing scholarly research to try to answer the question, and without posting the results of research, ought to be asking at [ell.se], not here.

Comment: @MετάEd Some situations are opportunities to learn and change one's rigid opinions. This is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but they do mean different things.

*When* specifies the time of the dream. You had a dream at the time you were walking, which is unlikely but possible.

*Where* means “in which”, so in this case it serves to specify the content of the dream.

> **where** *adverb*
>   **1** at, in, or to which (used after reference to a place or situation):
>       *I first saw him in Paris, where I lived in the early sixties*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/where)

Although the example given isn’t exactly analogous, the definition (“in which, used after a reference to a situation”) is exactly relevant.

> “Once, I had a dream in which I was walking...”

[Note the use of *once* to indicate a non-specific time in the past, not “one time”]

Comment: "... in which ..." is definitely superior. "... where ..." implies that the dream is a place. Metaphorically perhaps, but not literally.

Answer (score 4):

"Where I was walking..." is correct here. 'Where' denotes the place that the walking occurred and that place was your dream.

The first example:

"One time, I had a dream when I was walking..."

Implies that you were dreaming while taking a walk, which seems dangerous.